An app that registers in android system file explorer and shows clipboard content
Is there an app that registers in the android system's system file browser and always contains the current content of the clipboard? It might be helpful if you, for example don't want to download an image but want to upload it somewhere, but the field only has option to upload from file storage or "gallery".


Not sure I understand - what do you mean by registering in "file explorer"? The screenshot is broken.

I mean, SAF (Storage Access Framework), as shown on the screenshot. The app registers as a cotent provider and contains clipboard
